# how to remove unused plugin in pubspec.lock

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, webview-flutter

for example, i just change from webview_flutter to flutter_webview_pro.

and when i try flutter build apk --split-per-abi, this error comes out :

failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> Type io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /Users/mypc/ccc/myapps/build/webview_pro_android/.transforms/bdbf64f9d3abc9a772a513f41adb1eaa/classes/classes.dex, /Users/mypc/ccc/myapps/build/webview_flutter_android/.transforms/11582e4deb0c75876ac071bae0201050/classes/classes.de

after that i check pubspec.lock, .flutter-plugins and .flutter-plugins-dependencies, the previous packages 'webview_flutter' still remaining

i try creating new project but i don't have the same issues while change those packages, the pubspec.lock generate normally

Answer (score 1):

Delete `pubspec.lock` file.

then run `flutter clean`.

then run `flutter pub get`

after run above command `pubspec.lock` file ganerate automatically.